# Images not showing on secure page?

Tags: image, wordpress, ssl

Here's the page I'm working on:

http://www.texasshredderclassic.com/registration

The header area should look like it does on this page:

http://texasshredderclassic.com/contact-us/

I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that we're forcing SSL on the registration page? Any ideas on how to make these images show up, or do I need to provide more info? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is at https://texasshredderclassic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/TexasShredderClassicLogo3.png

If you click that link, you'll see that the problem is that your SSL certificate is only valid for **www**.texasshredderclassic.com, not texasshredderclassic.com.